# DropDownListFor does not write back selectedvalue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper, dropdownlistfor

I know there are more topics on this subject, but or I have a different problem, or i just do not understand the given solutions.
So a revisit for this topic
What am I missing here?

this reads the selected value into the selectedview property (and writes it back) So, this works just fine.

```
VIEW
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender,
                new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "m"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "f"},
                }
        , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

this reads the selected value into the selectedview property (but does NOT read is back)

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SchoolID,
                @* Model.SchoolList *@
                new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "School 1", Value = "1"},
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "School 2", Value = "2"},
                }
        , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form - control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchoolID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

model and database setup

MODEL

```
public string Gender { get; set; }
public string SchoolID { get; set; }


DATABASE TABLE
     [Gender] [varchar](50) NULL,
     [SchoolID] [int] NOT NULL,


DATABASE STORED PROCEDURE
    @Gender varchar(50),
    @SchoolID int
```

Something about `model.SchoolID` makes it that the selected value can be set correctly, but it does not return a changed selectedvalue to the model, even though `SchoolID` and Gender are both defined as string in the model. So for the `DropDownListFor` they both should be of the same type, right? And if so, then I have no clue why one is working and the other is not...
So, some light on this issue will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do the correct values get posted to the controller method?

Comment: `SchooIID` is `int` in your db, so should be `int` in your model, not `string`

Comment: @Chris - The Gender values is correctly posted  and refelectsthe user selection, but the SchoolID always stays the same.

Comment: @Stephen - I changed the int into a string to make sure the MVC part of the code is identical for both dropdownlistfor objects., but I do agree that I have to be doing something wrong here, because basically, the int is the only difference in the code (as far as I can tell). Is there a better way to do the string / int conversion inside the MODEL part?

Comment: Its an `int` so it should be and `int`! Why do you think you need to do some conversion (the `DefaultModelBinder` already does that for you)

Answer (score 0):

I had the next line of code in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SchoolID) ...
```

This disabled the update of the selectedvalue for dropdownlistfor (or to be more precise probably disabled the update of model.SchoolID by not posting the value?) Whatever the reason, removing this line solved the problem.

Thank you @Stephen, for your support, and thank you @Chris, for pointing me into the right direction.